# Create a nested dictionary during run time

Tags: python-3.x

I have data in a `.txt` file like below:

```
Destination  Transport_type  Route
A   Car   Route1
A   Bus   Route2
B   Car   Route3
B   Bus   Route4
```

Now, I need to make this into a dictionary with `"Destination"` as key and `"transport_type"` and `"route"` as nested dictionary during run time.

```py
for line in lines:
   destination, transport_type, route= line.split(' ')
   delivery_map[destination][transport_type] = route
```

But this fails with `KeyError`.

Can anybody please help?

Expected output is

```
{'A': {'Car': 'Route1', 'Bus': 'Route2'}, 'B': {'Car': 'Route3', 'Bus': 'Route4'}}
```

Comment: `print(pandas.read_csv("data.txt", delim_whitespace=True).to_json())` if you use `pandas` library.

Comment: Can you add in what you expect the output to look like?

Comment: Now, I am able to resolve ```KeyError``` but problem now is with duplicate destination in text file. So insead of expected output, I am getting like ``` {'A': {'Bus': 'Route2'}, 'B': {'Bus': 'Route4'}} ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are very close.  The problem is you have defined `delivery_map` as a dictionary, but you are accessing it as if it is a dictionary of dictionaries.  You assign `route` to the not-yet-initialized `transport_type` dictionary associated with `destination` resulting in a `KeyError`.  The simplest way to do what you want to do is to use the Python standard library `defaultdict` which can be used to initialize each top level value of `delivery_map` as a dictionary.

Example:

```
from collections import defaultdict

lines = [
    "A   Car   Route1",
    "A   Bus   Route2",
    "B   Car   Route3",
    "B   Bus   Route4",
]

delivery_map = defaultdict(dict)
for one_line in lines:
    destination, transport_type, route = one_line.split()
    delivery_map[destination][transport_type] = route
    
print(delivery_map)
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {'A': {'Car': 'Route1', 'Bus': 'Route2'}, 'B': {'Car': 'Route3', 'Bus': 'Route4'}})
```